# Vertical Bar Chart not displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, meteor, chart.js, bar-chart

Vertical bar chart:
[image]

I want to achieve this vertical bar chart image in the link above but the result of my code is displaying a normal bar chart. Here is a snippet of the code I'm using to generate the chart:

```js
<template name="VerticalCharts">
<div class="profile-user-box">
    <canvas id="myCharts"></canvas>
</div>
</template>

Template.VerticalCharts.onRendered(function() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myCharts').getContext('2d');
    var myCharts = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                  legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                  },
                  title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                  }
                }
              },
        });
});
```

Comment: show me your current chat screenshot image.

Comment: Your image is vertical chart. Show me your current chart.

Comment: For vertical chart, it needs data with negative and positive numbers.

Comment: @VadimOrlov212 Here is the link to the image https://ibb.co/tpYsT87, (what was displayed for me)

Comment: Is there negative data for vertical bar chart? Your datums are positive numbers.

Comment: @VadimOrlov212, setting the negative and positive data works fine. Thank you

Comment: If you are happy, i'm happy too.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a vertical bar chart, if you want horizontal bars you need to set the `indexAxis` to `'y'` in your options object like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I want both horizontal and vertical. Which means I will set both negative data and positive data